# Host How to filter network access for a windows 10 guest

Tags: networking, windows-10, libvirt, qemu, ubuntu-18.04

Ive setup a VM containing windows 10 Pro, but i would like to blacklist centrain dns entries and ip v4/v6 addresses. ive searched for bridged networks but did not found any matching solution.

is a virtual network interface a correct solution? and if yes how do i blacklist those connections?

My Goal is to prevent windows 10 from gathering data without installing an tool in win10

Host: 
Ubuntu 18.04
kernel 5.0.0-37-generic
AMD x1950 16-core
16 GB RAM

Guest:
Windows 10 Pro
8 virtual cores
4 GB RAM
Nvidia GTX 750 (Passthrought)

Comment: thx for the hint, added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the IP addresses you want to block, you can use the built-in Windows Firewall to filter the traffic.

You can either do it using the GUI (wf.msc) or with [netsh.exe advfirewall](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/947709/how-to-use-the-netsh-advfirewall-firewall-context-instead-of-the-netsh) or [PowerShell New-NetFirewallRule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/new-netfirewallrule?view=win10-ps).

If you don't know the IP address, and want to block by hostname, you could do so using [the Windows hosts file](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/block-websites-using-hosts-file/) (or the client DNS server if it is under your control).

Comment: while searching for an list of win 10 spy hosts ive found a nice tool that does not reqiere an install: [WindowsSpyBlocker](https://github.com/crazy-max/WindowsSpyBlocker) works like a charm an does the same as you suggested